# Bluemix Spark as a Service and Tableau 9.3

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api

I am running Tableau 9.3(trial software) on a Mac and have downloaded and installed the SimbaSparkODBC connector for Spark. 
I have tried using the Service Credentials on Bluemix for Spark as a Service using no Authentication, user name, user name and password, user name and password(SSL) - port is 10000

for user name I have tried using both tenant_id and tenant_id_full from the credentials. I have also tried hiveuser

for password I have used tenant_secret when using either tenant_id or tenant_id_full as the user name.

in a scala notebook I imported scala.sys.process._ to verify host ip I also tried to use netstat to verify port 10000 is listening but I couldn't see the port

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Tableau itself does not support Apache Spark](http://www.tableau.com/products/desktop#) as of right now, let alone the Bluemix Apache Spark Service. So Tableau itself cannot connect directly to the bluemxix spark service. The Simba Spark ODBC connector is what you would plug in to spark so that your spark programs can connect to odbc sources. Of course, you cannot use it to connect to spark to run spark programs.

Comment: Randy - FYI Tableau supports Spark, just not on Bluemix yet. There is support on Databricks